# SetSourceData correct call parameters

Tags: c#, excel

What is the correct call for the following sniplet

// this one throws an exception

```
Excel.Range range = worksheet.get_Range("A3", "B4");
myChart.SetSourceData(range.ToString(), Excel.XlRowCol.xlColumns); // Throws an
```

// the thrown Exception

```
Exception Source:      Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint
Exception Type:        System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
Exception Message:     Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a 
call to a COM component.
Exception Target Site: SetSourceData
```

### -------------------------------------------------------------

// this one doesnt compile

```
myChart.SetSourceData(range, Excel.XlRowCol.xlColumns);
```

// the compile errors

```
1>  error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.
PowerPoint.Chart.SetSourceData(string, object)' has some invalid arguments
1>  error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 
'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range' to 'string'
```

Comment: Please provide some details about the exception, and about the error message you get when trying to compile.

Comment: `SetSourceData(range.ToString()...` will throw an exception because it is expecting an `Excel.Range` object and not a string. As far as I can tell you are calling the method correctly in the one you say does not compile, but without further information it's difficult to tell.

Comment: @ZevSpitz : Thanks for the hint, I just added them

Comment: @SidHolland : Well, thats the point. It expects a string, and all the example I found in the net were with only range

Comment: @DougGlancy : I always tried accepted the correct answers in the time when I needed them.

Answer (score 1):

**SetSourceData** operates in completely different ways depending if you're using the method from the Excel library or another library such as PowerPoint:

Sub SetSourceData(Source As **Range**, [PlotBy])
    Member of Excel.Chart

Sub SetSourceData(Source As **String**, [PlotBy])
    Member of PowerPoint.Chart

In the PowerPoint model, the method is expecting a string which holds the address of the chart data range that contains the source data!

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff746759.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Same method operating in two different ways in two different MSO object models. Now that's clever Microsoft!

Answer (score 0):

This is actually fairly weird, most documentation defines the first range parameter as a range object but this actually should be passed as a string

```
wdChart.SetSourceData("Sheet1!$A$1:$B$4", oMissing);
```

Comment: Don't use standard sheet names ("Sheetn") in ms excel, google spreadsheet etc... The name is translated to the users language. So as I'm from germany, a new sheet is always called "Blattn"

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
myChart.SetSourceData(dataSheet.Name + "!" + dataSheet.UsedRange.Address, Excel.XlRowCol.xlColumns);
```

Update: It is important to get the datasheets name. If you need to select a specific range, not the whole sheet replace dataSheet.UsedRange with your range. I needed this and tested it. It worked.