# C# change SourceData of chart in excel

Tags: c#, excel

I have got a chart and the data has been inserted  so I have to extend the range of source data.

The original format
[image: data form]

line chart[image: line chart model]

I am just writing like this

```
sheet.ChartObjects(0).SetSourceData(sheet.get_Range("B2", columnA + 5),Excel.XlRowCol.xlColumns);
```

and the program shutdown at this and log reads "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException"

"HRESULT:0x800A03EC"

I don't know the error and I didn't know how to show the previous source data  range and format.If I can get the original source range with right format,I may modify  parameter  appropriately.

PS：I have found something here [setsourcedata-correct-call-parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789970/setsourcedata-correct-call-parameters)but I couldn't correct my code......

Comment: count starts from 1 `.ChartObjects(1)`

Comment: It failed again.@Slai

Comment: You can Record Macro in Excel of setting the data range manually, and compare the generated VBA code with yours https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Automate-tasks-with-the-Macro-Recorder-974ef220-f716-4e01-b015-3ea70e64937b

Comment: Yeah,thank you.I wonder why Microsoft  makes this method?And, why doesn't provide method to display the original SourceData ? @Slai